# Not the only one

Tags: riddle, word, language

> I am one, but not the only one.
>
> If you deify me, I leave.
>
> If you do something else to me, I give wisdom.
>
> If you take me, you are doing something that starts with me.

**What am I?**

Hint:

> The first line defines me. The other three lines refer to putting something in front of me.

Comment: In the 2nd line, is it meant to be _defy_ instead of deify?

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay Deify is the intended spelling

Comment: I guess it could be doing something with extraction of wisdom _tooth_ :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are:

> **PART**

```
I am one, but not the only one.
```

> If you are a PART, then you are one part of something but not the only part.

```
If you deify me, I leave.
```

> If you are "de"-ified, you become *DEPART*, and leave.

```
If you do something else to me, I give wisdom.
```

> If I instead prepend "im", you *IMPART* wisdom.

```
If you take me, you are doing something that starts with me.
```

> If I *TAKE PART*, then I am **PART**ICIPATING.

Comment: Exactly correct

Answer (score 4):

The logic is a bit wobbly, but are you...

> speed?

I am one, but not the only one.

> Unsure on this. Speed is a measurement, just like mass, force, and innumerable others. So one, but certainly not the only one.

If you deify me, I leave.

> **Godspeed** is a somewhat antiquated alternative to "goodbye", so if you say it, someone's leaving.

If you do something else to me, I give wisdom.

> **Bringing someone up to speed** means informing them regarding a situation.

If you take me, you are doing something that starts with me

> If you "take speed", you're **speeding up** (and "speeding" starts with "speed").

Comment: This is a clever answer, and makes good use of plays on words, but still not what I had in mind. +1 though

Answer (score 4):

I think you are:

> apart

I am one, but not the only one.

> a part by definition is one but not the only one.

If you deify me, I leave.

> Set apart - can mean deify and also putting something aside (weakest part of guess)

If you do something else to me, I give wisdom.

> pick apart - how you learn about something

If you take me, you are doing something that starts with me.

> take apart - starts with a part.

Comment: "Deify" could refer to qrcneg (ROT 13) and give wisdom could refer to vzcneg (ROT 13).  Sorry don't know how to add spoiler tags on stack exchange to a comment.

Comment: and the last one cnegnxr

Comment: puzzle-guesser: You got the first line mostly right but the others aren't what I was intending. @kevinomar Both of your interpretations are correct

Comment: @ngn I was thinking of a different word, but that also works

Answer (score 2):

I am

> Buddhism

I am one, but not the only one.

> There are three different schools of Buddhism, namely Theravada Buddhism, Mahayana Buddhism, and Vajrayana Buddhism

If you deify me, I leave.

> Buddhism is a non deity religion, hence incompatible with deifying- an act reserved towards godly creatures

If you do something else to me, I give wisdom.

> If you embrace Buddhism, you are on a trail towards enlightenment/nirvana.

If you take me, you are doing something that starts with me

> One of the most important practices of Buddhism is meditation.

Comment: This is an interesting answer, but not what I had in mind. The [tag:language] tag should be relevant to the answer. I also didn't really understand your interpretation of the last line

Comment: @ba Oh I see, I am a newbie here; I need to familiriaze my self with the tagging system here. For the last my idea was if you take Buddhism classes, an important aspect of it is doing me-ditation.

Answer (score 0):

You are:

> The indefinite article "a"

I am one, but not the only one.

> "A" refers to a single object, but in a way that implies there are many of that object.

If you deify me, I leave.

> Adding "dios" gives "adios," Spanish for "goodbye"

If you do something else to me, I give wisdom.

> Not sure on this one...

If you take me, you are doing something that starts with me.

> Taking anything could also be "acquiring" something, which starts with "a".

Comment: This is an interesting answer, but the answer I was thinking of doesn't require any language other than English

Answer (score 0):

Kind of jumping through some hoops here, but I'm guessing you are:

> Away (or "A Way")

I am one, but not the only one

> Away is "a way", but not the only way

If you deify me, I leave

> God + away = "got away"

If you do something else to me, I give wisdom

> Away + ken = "awaken" (as in an awakening of knowledge)

If you take me, you are doing something that starts with me

> Take a way = "wayfaring" (definitely my weakest part of this answer)

Again, I may have stretched the rules a bit, but this is what I've come up with so far.